# DevOps - Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1' in continuous integration build

Tags: c#, ms-access, azure-devops

I have a continuous build task in Azure DevOps which builds the solution whenever code is pushed to repository. So my code is building and running fine on my local machine, but when it tries to build in devOps, this error comes,
"`Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'`".
and build fails.
**Note: I am also using MS Access database with it and using its dlls as references.**

Following is the build log

```
  ##[section]Starting: VSBuild
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio build
Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
Version      : 1.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
==============================================================================
##[command]"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json
##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=1437a450-5179-47db-98bd-fe8e0723e344|SolutionDir=d:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.151.2\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_03117f94-5776-4b48-ae99-669bb78290be_build_3_0"
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 8/23/2019 1:40:52 PM.
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
ValidateProjects:
  The project "EDS.Attach.Installer" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.sln" (1) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.WinApp\EDS.Attach.WinApp.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.WinApp\EDS.Attach.WinApp.csproj" (2) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Business\EDS.Attach.Business.csproj" (3:2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Business\EDS.Attach.Business.csproj" (3:2) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj" (4:3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj" (4:3) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\EDS.Attach.Models.csproj" (7:4) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:d:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output Claim\AttachmentIdReceivedEventArgs.cs Claim\ClaimStatusChangedEventArgs.cs Claim\DeleteRequirementResponseModel.cs Claim\DeleteRequirementsDataModel.cs Claim\EvaluateClaimAttachmentRulesModel.cs Claim\GetAttachmentIdDataModel.cs EDSAnnotations\IntMaxLengthAttribute.cs EDSAnnotations\NonZeroAttribute.cs Payer\ADACodeModel.cs Common\APIResponseBaseModel.cs Claim\AttachmentDetailModel.cs Claim\CaptureAttachmentModel.cs Claim\ClaimAttachmentModel.cs Claim\ClaimsInProcessModel.cs Common\MethodCallBaseModel.cs Claim\GetClaimsDataModel.cs Payer\GetPayerRulesDataModel.cs Payer\PayerAttachementRulesModel.cs Payer\Payer.cs Payer\PayerAttachmentRule.cs Payer\PayerAttachmentRuleDescriptionModel.cs Settings\Practice.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Claim\SaveAttachmentResponseModel.cs Claim\SaveAttachmentDataModel.cs Settings\UserModel.cs "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
  Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EntityFramework.dll".
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.xml" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EntityFramework.xml".
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll".
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml".
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.pdb" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.pdb".
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.xml" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.xml".
  Creating "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\obj\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.csproj.CopyComplete" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
_CopyAppConfigFile:
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\App.Config" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.dll.config".
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\obj\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.dll" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.dll".
  EDS.Attach.Models -> d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.dll
  Copying file from "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\obj\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.pdb" to "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\bin\Release\EDS.Attach.Models.pdb".
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Models\EDS.Attach.Models.csproj" (default targets).
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): Warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4ac9e1da-5bad-4ac7-86e3-24f4cdceca28" version 12.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4ac9e1da-5bad-4ac7-86e3-24f4cdceca28" version 12.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj]
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): Warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit. [d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj]
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): Warning MSB3293: Could not resolve dependent COM reference "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): warning MSB3293: Could not resolve dependent COM reference "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8. [d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj]
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Business\EDS.Attach.Business.csproj" (3:2) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Data\EDS.Attach.Data.csproj" (5:3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Data\EDS.Attach.Data.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Business\EDS.Attach.Business.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.WinApp\EDS.Attach.WinApp.csproj" (2) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.DependencyInjection\EDS.Attach.DependencyInjection.csproj" (6:2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.DependencyInjection\EDS.Attach.DependencyInjection.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.WinApp\EDS.Attach.WinApp.csproj" (2) is building "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.UI\EDS.Attach.UI.csproj" (8:2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "bin\Release\".
  Creating directory "obj\Release\".
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.UI\EDS.Attach.UI.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.WinApp\EDS.Attach.WinApp.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.WinApp\EDS.Attach.WinApp.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
"d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Business\EDS.Attach.Business.csproj" (default target) (3:2) ->
"d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj" (default target) (4:3) ->
(ResolveComReferences target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): warning MSB3284: Cannot get the file path for type library "4ac9e1da-5bad-4ac7-86e3-24f4cdceca28" version 12.0. Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) [d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "ADODB". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit. [d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5): warning MSB3293: Could not resolve dependent COM reference "2a75196c-d9eb-4129-b803-931327f72d5c" version 2.8. [d:\a\1\s\EDS.Attach.Common\EDS.Attach.Common.csproj]

    3 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:13.90
##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: VSBuild
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DevOps - Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1' in continuous integration build

It seems you are using the COM library, which is not exists on the agent you pipeline runs.

This COM library should be registered in your local Windows' registery, but not on the build server, you can check for is if your COM library is registered in Windows' registery:

```
%windir%\system32\regsvr32 YourComLibrary.dll
```

Or you can execute your pipeline on your private agent, which is hosted on your local machine.

If you want to use it with hosted agent, you can try to included the dll's in the `**\bin\` folder and modify build process adding assemblies.

Check the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483300/errors-using-gac-msil-assemblies-on-vsts/43491241#43491241) for some more details.

Comment: I am using this 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao' COM library. Including the libraries in source code doesn't seem to be a good idea I guess

Comment: I resolved it by removing one unnecessary reference and then moved the other to a folder in solution and set its path in references accordingly and pushed the dll to repository. Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some nugget packages on this build ? If yes, do you use the "restore" command before the build one ?